# Show the level set of a convex function is convex but that the converse is not necessarily true

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following question:

**A level set of a function $f(x)$ is a set of the form $\{x : f(x) ≤ c\}$ for different constants $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Show that any level set of a convex function is also convex. Also, give an example to show the converse is NOT true, i.e., give an example of a simple 1-dimensional function such that any of its level sets is convex, but the function is not convex.**

For this I took two sets $C$ and $D$ such that:

$$D = \{x:f(x)\}\space x \in \Bbb R$$

and

$$C = \{x:f(x) \leq c\}\space x,c \in \Bbb R$$

so $C \subset D$ therefore if $\space x_1,x_2 \in C\space$ then $\space x_1,x_2 \in D$ and since $D$ is convex then $C$ must be convex.

I am stuck on proving the converse though, I get conceptually that I want a quasiconvex function such that any level set is convex. A few places I read that $\sqrt\mid x \mid$ fits the bill but I can't see how it does. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "$D=\{x:f(x)\}$" Sorry, but this makes no sense at all. And what does a level set of $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ look like?

Comment: No apologies needed, it has been some time since I have done math at this level and my notation is very spotty. I was trying to convey that D is a set of all values described by the function f(x). Therefore if the level set is a subset of that function then the resulting set is a subset of D. It's intuitive but I guess I'm not communicating it clearly.

Comment: It looks like you need to brush up your basic understanding of sets and functions before you are prepared to study convex analysis. For example, do you understand the difference between the set of values that are inputs to a function (the domain) and the set of values the function itself attains (the range)? Which of these is the level set $C$ a subset of?

Comment: $D=\{x:f(x)\}$ makes no sense because it isn't in the form of $\{\text{object}:\text{conditions}\}$. A "condition" is something that is true or false (e.g. $f(x)\le c$). $f(x)$ is a number, so it is neither true nor false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication

$ \quad\qquad$ convex function $\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad$ convex level sets

is straightforward. Let me provide a counter-example for the inverse implication. It can be $\ f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ given by:

$$ f(x)\ :=\ x+sin(x) $$

> *You may have a look at the graph if you have any doubts; then you
>   may follow by a proof*.

Answer (score 0):

In general functions with convex level sets are called *quasiconvex*. Such functions are characterised in such way: let $I\subset\Bbb R$ be a convex set (i.e. the interrval, maybe improper), $f:I\to\Bbb R$. The function $f$ is quasiconvex iff either $f$ is monotone or there exists $c\in \Bbb R$ s.t. $f$ is nonincreasing on $(-\infty,c)\cap I$ and $f$ is nondecreasing on $(c,\infty)\cap I$.